# Debian Unwanted Login Screen

Tags: linux, debian, login-screen

I have just installed Debian from CD 1, deselecting everything at the tasksel stage, even standard system utilities. I have installed `bspwm` and “bar ain’t recursive”, as well as `sxhkd`. However, whenever I boot Debian, an annoying Debian login screen appears that says "Welcome to *hostname*" (where *hostname* equals my hostname), with a big Debian logo on the right side. I cannot find a way to disable this, and I haven't explicitly activated it anywhere.

When booting, I can see it is starting X, but it is too fast to decode what it's doing exactly.

Comment: You can always switch back to the console screen from X11 with `ctrl-alt-F1`, there you can use `Shift-PgUp` to scroll back.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, the value of /etc/X11/default-display-manager was set to xdm, which enables this login screen. Simply delete all the text in /etc/X11/default-display-manager to disable it.

Comment: Is your goal to disable the display manager or bypass the login?